# How can I remove the header-scrollbar from FullCalendar-timeGridWeek view in Angular with FullCalendar library?

Tags: html, angular, fullcalendar, scrollbar

I'm using the FullCalendar-timeGridWeek view. There is a useless scrollbar at the header. How can I remove it?

[Here is a live example from FullCallendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timegrid-standard-view-demo)

These scrollbar is meant
[image]

I searched for solutions from the provider, but didn't found any.